# UserId undefined-socket io /node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to use socket.io for a while but I faced some problem in `emit` data to client side

the code works perfectly but I keep getting `not defined` for `userId` on the `client side` see below

```
server.js 

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`)

})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
    res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        console.log(roomId, userId)
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('connect', userId)
        console.log(userId)
    })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

client

```
const socket = io('/')
const $events = document.getElementById('events');
const newItem = (content) => {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.innerText = content;
    return item;
  };
socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, 10) // 10 here is the userId
socket.on('connect', function(userId) {

    $events.appendChild(newItem('user connected:' + userId)); // the userId ==== undefined
  
})
```

**the is the error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Update your server file like shown below

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        console.log(roomId, userId)
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.to(roomId).emit('connect', userId)
        console.log(userId)
    })
})
```